Is the following method for proving density of irrational numbers in real numbers without using rational numbers density in real numbers rigorous?
The motivation for this question is:
I told my friend to use:
$\forall x_{1}, x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}, x_{1} < x_{2}, \exists r \in \mathbb{Q}: x_{1} < r <x_{2}.$
To prove:
$\forall x_{1}, x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}, x_{1} < x_{2}, \exists s \in \mathbb{Q^{c}}: x_{1} < s <x_{2}.$
But what surprised me is: He proved it without using the density of rational numbers in $\mathbb{Q}$ as following:
By contradiction:
Assume $\exists x_{1}, x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}, x_{1} < x_{2},  \forall s \in \mathbb{Q^{c}}: s \notin(x_{1},x_{2}).$
Thus $(x_{1},x_{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}$, this leads to the contradiction, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable infinite, where $(x_{1},x_{2})$ is uncountable.
Is this method good and rigrous to prove it?
My reason for checking is that this method may be circular without realizing that  or it may depend on density of rationals implicitly, so that I want your opinions.

This proof is fine. It uses two things:

The rationals are countable. This can be proven by constructing a surjection from the natural numbers to the rationals, without using the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$, or really anything about real numbers.

An open interval in $\mathbb R$ is uncountable. This statement has nothing to do with the rational numbers, so unsurprisingly, it can be proven without using anything about $\mathbb Q$.


